# Datagrid get hidden cell from sellected row

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, wpfdatagrid

Hi i have problem with accessing hidden value in `DataGrid` of selected `Row`:

```
<DataGrid Name="grid" ItemsSource ="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id_user" Binding="{Binding id_user}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="A" Binding="{Binding A}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="B" Binding="{Binding B}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="selectRow"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

This is code witch I use to do that, but I got that element doesnt exist.

```
private void selectRow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView row = (DataRowView)grid.SelectedItems[0];
    var x = row["Id_user"];
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new PageA((string)x));
}
```

Is there a simply way to do that?

**EDIT:**

`row["ID"]` is not `SelectedItem.id`. This is diffrent *value*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move this logic to viewmodel. Event handler in code behind should look like this:

```
private void selectRow(object sender,RoutedEventArgs  e) 
{
    ViewModel.Navigate();
}
```

And here is `Navigate()` implemetation:

```
public void Navigate()
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new PageA(SelectedItem.id_user));
}
```

All thats left to do is to bind `SelectedItem` property on view model to your `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid Name="grid" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource ="{Binding Collection}"  IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
```

Comment: SelectedItem.id != row["ID"]

Comment: I knew i should write this at the begining that is diffrent :/

Comment: no, this is id from `var x = row["Id"];`, where `row` is your selected item. Edit your code, plz, if that is not the case.

Comment: ok i edited. Now it should be not mistaken with SelectedItem.id.

Comment: but how to bind SelectedItem to selected row? I am newbe at xaml and it will take me weeks to find that.

Comment: You should do some reading on mvvm pattern and wpf. Here is something to get you started: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial